# extjs IDE for faster development

Tags: extjs

Is there a good IDE available for extjs development? So that you do not need to refer to API to see which events/methods are supported by a object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an Aptana plugin (Eclipse based plugin for Aptana IDE).. I have not used it though. May be you can give it a try.

You can get the plugin from Sencha forum - Link: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?89417-3.X.X-Aptana-plugin

Answer (score 1):

There are plugins for Eclipse, Spiket IDE and Aptana that will do code-suggest.  However, you should always refer to the API as there may be cases where nuances to the functionality can be understood.  There are often in-depth  examples of how the code must be implemented to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

i use eclipse and spket plugin...
spket also support other js framework, like jquery, prototype, YUI, etc

Miha Trtnik. have a good article to that.
http://www.webeks.net/extjs/eclipse-javascript-plugin-ext-js.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply looking for code completion [spket](http://spket.com/) and [aptana studio](http://www.aptana.com/) are the way to go.