# IDE support for extjs apps

Tags: eclipse-plugin

Any IDE for development or plugins available for development. Actually I'm using eclipse in java. Thanks if have plug-in for that.

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280983/extjs-ide-for-faster-development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use your own development environment. Since It is providing plug-in [see here](http://spket.com/download.html) . And detailed process [here](http://spket.com/extjs.html)